# Equivalent of .publish(Function<T, R>) for ParallelFlux<T> Reactor 3

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have some Reactor Flux like this:

```
SomeFlux.map(thing -> makeOtherThing(thing))
        .publish(fluxFunction)
        .subscribe();
```

Where the argument to `.publish()` is `fluxFunction` which is an object of an implementation of the Java 8
`Function<T, R>` functional interface like so:

```
public class FluxFunction implements Function<Flux<OtherThing>, Flux<DiffOtherThing>> {
  @Override
  Flux<DiffOtherThing> apply(Flux<OtherThing>) {
    // some code which "consumes" incoming Flux and outputs another
  }
}
```

My question is, If I change the above code to:

```
SomeFlux.parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.parrallel())
        .map(thing -> makeOtherThing(thing))
        .publish(fluxFunction)
        .subscribe();
```

The method .publish(fluxFunction) is invalid as I am now dealing with a ParallelFlux, is there some equivalent to .publish(Function<>) I can use on a parallelFlux? and if so How would I have to edit my Function implementation in order to accomodate this?

Comment: Some more context here would be nice, why the parallel Flux, what does `makeOtherThing` do and why do you need `publish` on a `ParallelFlux`. User case?

Answer (score 0):

So what appears to be the equivalent (at least in my case) is:

```
SomeFlux.parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .map(thing -> makeOtherThing(thing))
        .as(fluxFunction) // changed ".publish()" to ".as()" 
        .subscribe()
```

where I have also re-defined `fluxFunction` as:

```
// Now operates on ParallelFlux<> rather than Flux<>
public class FluxFunction implements Function<ParallelFlux<OtherThing>, ParallelFlux<DiffOtherThing>> {
  @Override
  ParallelFlux<DiffOtherThing> apply(ParallelFlux<OtherThing>) {
    // some code which "consumes" incoming ParallelFlux and outputs another
  }
}
```

This appears to be working perfectly for me.

I Hope this helps anyone who finds themselves in a similar bind.